# jQuery: Post form to a modal window for previewing the entered data

Tags: jquery

I am looking for a way to use jQuery to allow a user to look at a modal window "preview" of a form before they submit the form to be saved.

I have this working with javascript, the form is posted to a file named preview.php that iterates through the posted information. The script currently opens a new window.

I would like instead to use jQuery to post the form to a modal window for previewing. Does anyone have any thoughts on how to do this?

This is what I am currently using:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function preview(form) {
  form.target='_blank';
  form.action='http://example.com/preview.php';
  form.submit();
}
</script> 
<input type="button" value="preview" onclick='preview(this.form)'>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the http://jquery.malsup.com/ form plugin. Add an empty div with a id of 'preview'.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#form').ajaxForm({ 
        target: '#preview', 
        url: 'http://example.com/preview.php' 
    }); 
});
```

The form will be posted to the preview.php file and return any text that is printed in that file.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to pass your form data to the PHP page...To do this, serialize and stringify your form and its elements and pass them in the url.

**JavaScript / HTML**

```
<form action="javascript:void(0)" onsubmit="preview(this);">
    <input name="bodyBgColor" value="#ffffff" />
</form>

<div id="previewDiv" class="modal"></div>

$.fn.serializeObject = function(){
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name]) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
}; 

function preview(form) {
    var json = JSON.stringify( $(form).serializeObject() );
    var url ='/preview.php?j=' + encodeURIComponent(json);
    $('#previewDiv').load(url);
    return(false);
}
```

**preview.php**

```
<?php
    $json = $_REQUEST['j'];
    $j = json_decode($json, true);

    // 'bodyBgColor' is the name of the input element you want the value for.
    $bodyBGColor= $j['bodyBgColor']; 
?>

<html>
    <body style="background:#<?php echo $bodyBGColor ?>;">
        This is a preview using BGColor: <?php echo $bodyBGColor ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Obviously you want to avoid using inline styling, but you get the idea.

Comment: thanks dutchie432, but doesn't this just sends the form as a $_GET instead of a $_POST? I am looking to post the form to a modal window.

Comment: the `window.open` bit will open it in a new window. if you're trying to load that preview.php page into a modal div for previewing purposes, you can use the same logic to calculate the json and the url, but load the resulting PHP into a div with the id `divId`... `$('#divId').load(url);` and then show the modal dialog as you normally would.

Comment: Thanks Dutchie, plus one for your help, it pointed me in right direction. I have used the jquery form plugin, it allows me to post the form to the server and returns whatever is echoed in the php file.