# Update a specific row in an html table - ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am outputting data from a query to an html table for representation. On the Right corner of the table I have an "Update" button and a "Delete" button.

What I am trying to do is:

- When I press on the update button a modal opens. Inside that modal I have a form which I want to have predefined the values from the current row and be able to edit the specific row
- When I press the delete button on a row I want that row to be deleted and reload the page

This is my html table, the last two columns on the right are the buttons

```
 **Survey Name**    **Category**    **Weight**  **Update**  **Delete**
 Consultation   Ambiance                 20         Update  Delete
 Consultation   Consultation             40         Update  Delete
 Consultation   Follow Up                40         Update  Delete
```

This is my first query which generates the table

```
<cfquery name="categories" datasource="#dsn#">
        select s.name, s.id as surveyid, rc.categoryname, rc.id as categoryid, sc.cweight 
        from survey_categories sc
        join surveys s on s.id = sc.surveyidfk
        join rating_categories rc on rc.id = sc.categoryidfk
        where sc.surveyidfk='#form.survey#'
    </cfquery>
```

This is the form I am accessing when I press "Update"

- This form has an extra cfloop around the select tag to get the rest of the categories that I have in the database in case the user needs to change the category.
- So, for example if I pressed the update button on the second row on my table this form should have `Consultation` in the drop down menu and the number `40` on the bottom textbox
- A small note that may help, the first query that outputs the table also output a unique id with the pair (id, surveyName, Category, Weight). So the update query in the end would be something like

  `update categories set category='Example', weight='30'
  where id='345'`

I don't know how much this can help.

```
<cfoutput>
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Update</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
         <form name="update" action="updateSCpair.cfm" method="post">
            <input type="text" value="#categories.name#" class="input-xlarge" disabled> <br />
            <select name="categories">
                <cfloop query="ratingCat">
                  <option value="#ratingCat.id#" >#ratingCat.categoryName#</option>
                </cfloop>
            </select>
            <br />
            <input  class="span3" type="number" placeholder="Enter Category Weight" required >

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    </cfoutput>
```

**UPDATE**
TO make it more clear because I think I wrote too much. I need to call a modal on form submittion. I will need to replace my current buttons with a form and then pass all the data through hidden variables. The problem is that this is not working for me. I found another example here but it doesn't seem to work. [EXAMPLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598326/jquery-post-form-to-a-modal-window-for-previewing-the-entered-data)

Comment: So what isn't working? When you submit the update form, you should be able to reload the page with the rendered table, and the values of the query should reflect the update, assuming the update query was successful. Re: the delete action, people will often wrap the delete button/icon/whatever in a small form that submits the id of the row to a processing page that will delete it. You could also use an AJAX request to accomplish the same thing on click of the delete button.

Comment: well, when I press update the values that are being carried over to the popup do not reflect the values that I really want to update

Comment: Please use cfqueryparam otherwise you're leaving yourself open to SQL injection

Comment: I already made that change @duncan thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think the simplest way is to have two forms at the end of each row.  You already have the buttons.  The rest can be hidden fields.

Your update form would have a target attribute to launch your popup.  Since you already have the values from your query, you just submit them to the popup as hidden fields.

Your delete form would submit to the current coldfusion page.  At the start of the page, you would have something like this:

```
<cfif StructKeyExists(form, "DeleteMeOrSomethingLikeThat")>
code to delete record
</cfif>
```

This will get you started.  If you want to improve it later on, you can.

Finally, do one thing at a time.

Comment: I did not start the delete button yet, its just there. Thanks for help though i will try your method.